# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'city'

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-9

**Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'city'**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreUserRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserRequest;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserPhotoRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\City;


class CityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('users_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, 'Forbidden');


        $city = city::join('city', 'city.state_id', '=', 'state.state_id')
                    ->get(['state.state_name', 'city.city_name']);

        return view('admin.cities.index',compact('city'));

    }

}
```

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'city'
SELECT `state`.`state_name`, `city`.`city_name` FROM `city` INNER JOIN `city` ON `city`.`state_id` = `state`.`state_id`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use the join like this

```
$city = DB::table('city')
            ->join('state', 'city.state_id', '=', 'state.state_id')
            ->get(['state.state_name', 'city.city_name']);
```